# adding contents with multiple files using awk, sed or grep

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, terminal

I have to files named file 1 and filed 2 following format:

file 1 with 18000 lines

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5

-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10000024
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10000024
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
```

and file 2

```
COL 1            COL 2

tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
tom_fa_10000024 Alfin-like
tom_fa_10011338 C2C2-Dof
tom_fa_10003474 C2C2-Gata
tom_fa_10003291 C2H2
tom_fa_10007064 C2H2
tom_fa_10008972 C2H2
tom_fa_10009025 C2H2
tom_fa_10005726 C3H
tom_fa_10011317 C3H
tom_fa_10010708 CPP
tom_fa_10002138 E2F-DP
tom_fa_10009443 G2-like
tom_fa_10008970 GRAS
```

I want to do if colum 5 of (file 1) and colum 1 (file 2) are equal, add at a colum 6 in file 1 corresponding with col 2 (file 2)

so it would look like

```
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10005086   ABI3VP1
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086   ABI3VP1
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086   ABI3VP1
-   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086   ABI3VP1
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086   ABI3VP1
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086   ABI3VP1
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10005086   ABI3VP1
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10013928   ABI3VP2
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10000024   Alfin-like
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10000024   Alfin-like
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
```

I tried with fgrep -f file 2 file1 but i don't know how to merge the information of the colum 2 file 2. and the strings are no equal.

Comment: (1) “add a column 6 in file 2” — but file 2 has only two columns.  Do you want to add columns 3, 4 and 5?  (2) Look at `join`.

Comment: Have you looked at the `join` command? It will join lines of two files based on a shared field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one pass, this `sed` script will work:

```
sed '/^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/{H;d;};G;s/ \([^ ]*\)\n.*\n\1 \([[:print:]]*\).*/ \1   \2/;P;d' file2 file1
```

What does it do? It collects all lines of `file2` in the hold space as a kind of lookup table, then appends this table to each line of the pattern space and does add the sixth column if the pattern was found. In detail:

- `/^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/` matches lines with two columns, only for those, the following command (commands inside `{}` is executed
- `{H;d;}` appends the lines to the hold space and stops further processing of the line, thus the rest of the script is only executed for lines of `file1`
- `G` appends the hold space with our lookup table to the pattern space
- `s/ \([^ ]*\)\n.*\n\1 \([[:print:]]*\).*/ \1   \2/` does append the sixth column for a match
- `P` prints the line without the appended table
- `d` suppresses other output (option `-n` would have done the same)

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below commands and it worked fine too

```
Step1

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5];next}($1 in a){print $0}' file1 file2 > u.txt
count=`awk '{print NR}' u.txt | sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`

step2

for ((i=1;i<=$count;i++)); do h=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $1}' u.txt`; j=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $2}' u.txt `; awk -v h="$h" -v j="$j" '$5 == h {$6=j;print $0}' file1; done >file3.txt


step3

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($5 in a){print $0}' file2 file1 >file4.txt


Step4(Final output)

awk '{print $0}' file3.txt file4.txt
- . ID = tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
- 0 Parent = tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
- 0 Parent = tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
- 2 Parent = tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
- 1 Parent = tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
- 0 Parent = tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
- 0 Parent = tom_fa_10005086 ABI3VP1
+ . ID = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 0 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 0 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 0 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 0 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 2 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 2 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 1 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 1 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 2 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
+ 2 Parent = tom_fa_10013928 ABI3VP2
- . ID = tom_fa_10000024 Alfin-like
- 0 Parent = tom_fa_10000024 Alfin-like
-   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
-   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10004587
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10018753
+   .   ID  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   0   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   1   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
+   2   Parent  =   tom_fa_10007441
```

Comment: Let me know reason for downvote